# Cloud-Optimized GeoTIFF overlay on Leaflet?

Tags: raster, leaflet, javascript, geotiff-tiff, web-mapping

I want to load external Cloud-Optimized GeoTIFF files onto a Leaflet map as overlays, and manipulate the colors based on user input. I've found examples online that appear to to this exact thing, but with OpenLayers: https://geotiffjs.github.io/cog-explorer/

I've also found a few Leaflet plugins, of various age and stability, but they all appear to have caveats:

- My COG files are big, so it would need to load parts of the tiff file on demand depending on map position/zoom, (rather than the whole file at once as you would with a regular raster overlay). The OpenLayers demo above does this.
- Ideally, we could do this with EPSG 3857 projection

Is Leaflet capable of doing this?

Comment: By specifying "Leaflet (or Mapbox GL) map" you're branching this into two questions, then you added a request for "popular" solution(s), and tacked on an additional question about color tweaking with tile servers. GIS SE uses a Focused question/Best answer model. The [Chat] feature would be a better place for discussion-oriented questions, but Chat is *underutilized*, so I doubt you'd get the information you need there. Please [Edit] your Question to tighten the focus to fit our model.

Comment: That's my bad; Leaflet and Mapbox have similar APIs and I was at my wit's end when I asked it. I've updated the question to remove the non-leaflet stuff.

Comment: Apart from loading parts of the tiff out of the box (you would have to cut it on the server side to appropriate chunks and then load on demand, depending on the view extent), Leaflet is capable of this, of course with the help of plugins.

Comment: With cloud-optimized geotiffs, you can use HTTP "RANGE" requests to only load chunks of the file at a time, and then it loads in kind of like tiles.

Comment: Any progress on this @DMack?

Comment: We did end up getting it to work somehow. I no longer have access to the app, but I think we used leaflet-geotiff-2 and plotty, as described in this example: https://github.com/onaci/leaflet-geotiff-2
We hosted our COGs on an S3-style bucket on DigitalOcean object storage. It all worked fairly well, but the hard part was getting the COGs in the right format for the map library. @staf - I hope that helps point you in the right direction!

Comment: @staf I asked some former teammates today about the project, and we remembered that we ended up using Titiler - https://developmentseed.org/titiler/ - to generate raster tiles on the fly, and then we just added them to the map like any other raster layer. I don't think we ended up using leaflet-geotiff-2 in production for performance reasons.